# How to add key to global ssh_known_hosts without ssh-keyscan?

Tags: ssh

I want to add an entry to my `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file without running `ssh-keyscan`. I tried adding the public key but ssh complains, that the fingerprint does not match.

From the sshd man page:

> SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS   FILE FORMAT
>
> ```
>  The /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and ~/.ssh/known_hosts files contain host
>  public keys for all known hosts.  The global file should be prepared by
>  the administrator (optional), and the per-user file is maintained auto-
>  matically: whenever the user connects to an unknown host, its key is
>  added to the per-user file.
> ```

So my take from that would be, that one can add the public key data. However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

My `ssh_known_hosts` looks like this: (the key part matching the content of my public key file)

```
192.168.1.208 ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza......zktpC1w==
```

running ssh-keyscan gives:

```
192.168.1.208 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2V...2L0=
192.168.1.208 ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...38Ll
192.168.1.208 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3Nza...m2Sc
```

So I can see, that the key shown for ssh-rsa ends differently from the content in my public key file.

How can I add the correct data to `ssh_known_hosts` file without `ssh-keyscan`?

(My environment: I use puttygen to create the keys, ssh-keygen etc. in a cygwin environment to convert as needed. Eventually the keys are used in Alpine linux VMs to ssh / scp between the VMs.)

Comment: You mean you created a user private/public key pair? This is different from the SSH host keys. If you want to authenticate a specific user, the user's public key has to go into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the target computer.

Comment: Which key is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - they brought me on the right track. There were a couple of copy and paste errors in my Vagrantfile and the puppet manifests. Fixing those made things work well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could possibly collect the public keys corresponding to the host keys using e.g. the shell module of Ansible (this should also be idempotent btw.):

```
for i in /etc/ssh/*.pub
do
    printf "$(hostname) "
    awk '{print $1, $2}' ${i}
done
```

This will output something like:

```
<host> ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE....vstxo4xdk3rms=
<host> ssh-ed25519 AAAAC....Wg3XxwzL
<host> ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza....83u3X
```

I am relying on the fact, that the public keys have 3 space separated fields usually of which the third is a comment that you don't need. Usually it is `root@<hostname>` so you could also do something like:

```
for i in /etc/ssh/*.pub
do
    awk '{print gensub(".*@", "", 1, $3), $1, $2}' ${i}
done
```

With that, you should be able to collate your ssh_known_hosts. Using Ansible or a similar tool, you could even gather the IP and FQDN on the corresponding host and extend the ssh_known_hosts using also IPs (for the case you want to connect and DNS doesn't work or just for completeness) or alternative (DNS) names.